# Visualize test and training set distribution with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to visualize the distribution of a dataset and it's splits into test and training data to check if the split is stratified.

The minimal example uses the iris dataset. It has a `species` column which is a factor with 3 levels. The following code snippet will show a nice plot with the count for each label, however I would like to see the percentage/probability for the labels in the respective set to see the distribution of the training and test sets.

```
library("tidyverse")
data(iris)
n = nrow(iris)
idxTrain <- sample(1:n, size = round(0.7*n), replace = F)
train <- iris[idxTrain,]
test <- iris[-idxTrain,]

iris$Set <- rep("Train", time = nrow(iris))
iris$Set[-idxTrain] <- "Test"

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, fill = Set)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

[image: Iris dataset train and test sample counts]

I tried calculating the percentage as shown below however this does not work, because it shows the percentage of the whole dataframe which shows a distribution similar to the counts.

```
geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)))
```

**How can I plot the percentage of each label within each set efficiently?**

Bonus: Including the whole dataset, train and test.

Answer (score 0):

```
library("tidyverse")
data(iris)
n = nrow(iris)
idxTrain <- sample(1:n, size = round(0.7*n), replace = F)
train <- iris[idxTrain,]
test <- iris[-idxTrain,]

iris$Set <- rep("Train", time = nrow(iris))
iris$Set[-idxTrain] <- "Test"
```

you need a separate dataframe for the labels

```
df_labs <- 
 iris %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>% 
 count(Set) %>% 
 mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) %>% 
 filter(Set == "Test")
```

that you use as the data for the label geom (or text)

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, fill = Set)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_label(data = df_labs, aes(label = scales::percent(pct), y = n / 2))
```

[image]

Comment: This goes in the right direction, however I would need the percentage of both the training and test data for each class to examine if both sets are distributed equally. In general I would favour the percentage to be on the y-axis.